# how to push text values to their parent and siblings div. using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, closest

I need to select all values from following input fields to their respective divs.. see bellow

```
<div id='table_row_div'>
  <div id='txtbox'><input type=text name='from' value='<?php echo $someVal?>'></div>
  <div id='splited'>
    <div new="0"><div>i want text's splited value here</div>
    <div new="1"><div>i want text's splited value here</div>
    <div new="2"><div>i want text's splited value here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These input text fileds contains (1,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1) type values... 
The above block is about 49 times... and i want an automated system that splits the text value, and push only "one" character on each next div of attr(new);

how can i do this using jquery. i tried following type of code..

```
var inputVal = $("#table_row_div #txtbox input");
var arrayFromDB = inputVal.val().split(',');


inputVal.closest('div').closest('div').find('div[new~="0"]').text(arrayFromDB[0]);
inputVal.closest('div').closest('div').find('div[new~="1"]').text(arrayFromDB[1]);
inputVal.closest('div').closest('div').find('div[new~="2"]').text(arrayFromDB[2]);
```

But this doesn't work...

Comment: If this block is repeated many times then you're creating hugely invalid XHTML.  An `ID` should be used once and once only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first - don't use an `ID` more than once.  IDs are designed to be unique.

Change your `IDs` for classes if they're not going to be unique.

You can implement the solution you need like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='table_row_div'>
    <div>
        <input type='text' class='txtbox' name='from' value='<?php echo $someVal?>'>
    </div>
    <div class='split'>
        <div new="0">First split value</div>
        <div new="1">Second split value</div>
        <div new="2">Third split value</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.txtbox').each(function() {
    var arrayFromDB = $(this).val().split(',');
    var splitDiv = $(this).closest('.table_row_div').find('.split');
    $('div[new~="0"]', splitDiv).text(arrayFromDB[0]);
    $('div[new~="1"]', splitDiv).text(arrayFromDB[1]);
    $('div[new~="2"]', splitDiv).text(arrayFromDB[2]);
});
```

[**Working demo on jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/en6tq/).

Comment: @Town.. **beautifull.. excellent.. .really helped.. lovely...**

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you properly close the div tags with the "new" attribute.

Comment: Actually i wrote these codes just to show the method i'm using.. actual code is enough lengthy... :)